# ANTLR4 Swift grammar cannot identify a for-in statement

Tags: java, swift, eclipse, antlr4

I am using ANTLR4 to parse Swift code using the Swift grammar (or at least based on it) from GitHub. The parser does not identify the for-in statement as a loop statement / for-in statement even if it was defined in the grammar. I am trying to understand why.

Thanks,
Roy

I am attaching these files via OneDrive:

[GameScene.swift](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aq_eUpdfbjXEchJuN_Rt4Hm_kmY)
[Swift.g4](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aq_eUpdfbjXEc9ezXc0NGBTuLGs)

Comment: Just a glance, but your grammar cannot distinguish `trailing_closure` and `code_block`.

Comment: Well, it did in other unit and i use this recognition of both trailing_closure and code_block so i guess that isn't the issue. In this case it doesn't recognize the for-in as a loop statement but instead as an expression or binary expression.

Answer (score 0):

OOPer, upon further investigating i did found out the problem was that the parser was wrongly identifying the 'for' as a variable / regular identifier.
So, i looked in GitHub swift grammar that they indeed separated the identifier to 2 types to avoid such things.

After i did that, the parser identified the for loop statement correctly...

Thanks

Bye